# Active leaderboard in Google Sheets (Score)

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iBfDM3NyhuLLxH2hD6mL-0u0-iddwKdO2RwrmZullbU/edit?usp=sharing

I need help creating a leader board where H1-3 Is The first,second,third place in score from b1-9 and I1-3 is the name of the person from a1-9. can anyone help

Comment: If googl-sheets why tag Excel?

Comment: But look into `LARGE()`

Comment: @ScottCraner wasnt thinking

Comment: @ScottCraner Will It Also Insert the name from A1-9 into the I1-3 like an actual leaderboard

Comment: You would then use INDEX/Match to return the name.

Comment: What am i doing wrong `=LARGE(B1:9, 1 =INDEX(A1:9))` i want it to return the name of the highest ranked person from their score in the b colum, same with second and third

Comment: `INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(B:B,1),B:B,0))`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:B9, "select B,A order by B desc limit 3", 0)
```

[image: 0]